# Run a batch file when windows activates/deactivates "Night Light"

Tags: cmd.exe, time

pretty new here. as title says, im trying to sync a program to run and close with sunset. just need a little help figuring out how. im wondering if i can use the windows nightlight setting to start the batch whenever it turns on or off.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to run this as a scheduled task as the currently logged in user, but you can achieve this by monitoring the registry.

The key you monitor to see what the status is:

```
HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\Cache\DefaultAccount\$$windows.data.bluelightreduction.bluelightreductionstate
```

Reading from the registry is done via the `REG QUERY` command. This command can be used to retrieve values of any key from within the registry.
Syntax:

```bsh
REG QUERY [ROOT\]RegKey /v ValueName [/s] 
REG QUERY [ROOT\]RegKey /ve --This returns the (default) value
```

Where RegKey is the key that needs to be searched for in the registry.
[Details about `REG QUERY`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-query)

Based on the result, you start or stop a task/program or whatever you want to do. 
Some sample code to get you started:

```bsh
@echo off
setlocal
set Key=HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\Cache\DefaultAccount\$$windows.data.bluelightreduction.bluelightreductionstate
set Type=REG_SZ
set Value=1
set Data=

for /f "tokens=2,3" %%a in ('reg query %Key% /v %Value% 2^>NUL ^| find /i "%Value%"') do (
    set TestType=%%a
    set Data=%%b
)
if /i not "%TestType%"=="%Type%" goto :Data_Missing
if /i "%Data%"=="0" goto Data_0
if /i "%Data%"=="1" goto Data_1
if /i "%Value%"=="1" goto Execute_P
goto Data_Undefined
   
:Execute_P  
echo Value is "%Value%". - Executing program
Start ""  "C:\Program Files\MY_FOLDER\my_program.exe"
REM notice the double quote after start IF the path contains spaces  
goto end

:Data_0
echo Data is "%Data%".
goto end
    
:Data_1
echo Data is "%Data%".
goto end
    
:Data_Missing
echo Key or value not found.
goto end
    
:Data_Undefined
echo No action for data "%Data%" defined.
    
:end
```

Please check these values in your registry as I am at the moment working on a MAC:

```bsh
set Type=REG_SZ
set Value=1
```

The batch has to run as a recurring task in the scheduler (5-10 min) to check for the change. If you are fluent in C++, you can write a monitor to check for the event, but that's another story.